# Putting a variable inside render() return - React Native

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am `mapping` json data and can `console.log` my result, but I can't insert those values in the render.

Here is the code I have for my render:

```
data_use = responseJson;
     const result_id = data_use.map(function(val) {
      return val.id;
    }).join(',');
    console.log(result_id);
render(){
return(

     <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>
      <View>
       <Card>          
          <View>
          <Text>{result_id}</Text>
         </View>
       </Card>
       </View>
     </View>
   );
  }
```

The error that I am getting is `ReferenceError: result_id is not defined`. Which is odd because it is defined?

Comment: where `map` code you put? It is inside any function or outside class

Comment: Where is that `result_id` calculation? That error means the variable isn't available in `render()` scope.

Comment: My `map` code is above the `render()` and everything is inside the class. Except the css.

Comment: you need to learn some React fundamentals like where to make async requests and how to set the response to state and render it out

Comment: This is because you are using const value for showing in render with data from an api call and intially the value is not there hence the undefined error. Post the code which you have used to call the api. Only in its response you can trigger a rerender which will make you show the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach will be useful if the data is loaded from a server.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     data : []
  };

}

componentDidMount() {
   // Your code to fetch data from server

   this.setState({ data: your_array_from_fetch });
}

render(){
   return(
     <View style={ styles.MainContainer }>
        <View>
           <Card>          
              <View>
                {
                   this.state.data.length > 0 ?
                       this.state.data.map((val, index) => {
                           return (
                              <Text key={index}>val.id</Text>
                           );
                       } ).join(',');
                    : null
                 }
              </View>
           </Card>
         </View>
      </View>
  );
}
```

I made few assumption from my side and I believe this is what you want! If any issue write that down below.

EDIT:

1. Yoganode issue can be fixed by testing if the data array length is greater than zero. This usually happens when render does not return anything.
2. I used `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` because `componentWillMount` is deprecated.

Try this conditional render

```
{
    this.state.data.length > 0 ?
        this.state.data.map((val, index) => {
           if (some_var == another_var) {
              return (
                 <Text key={index}>val.id</Text>
              );
           }
        }).join(',');
    : null
}
```

Comment: I like it, but I got this error: `Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure funtion!`. Should the `key` be in `View`? @RaajNadar

Comment: Try my 2nd approach probable you are loading data from server? Right, Yes the key is required because it is the only unique attribute to target a specific element.

Comment: That's right, also, my json data from that server is already in an object. I found the reason behind the `Yoganode` error, how do I test this if the data is loaded?

Comment: I updated my answer with lots of information and tested code! @LaneyWilliams

Comment: I'm sorry, I appreciate all of this, but I just can't get pass that error even when I changed `val.id` to just  'Hi'.

Comment: Make a snack if you are using Expo!

Comment: I can't, I don't have expo. Should I paste my entire code?

Comment: Sure if there is no sensitive data paste the code but don't remove the old!

Comment: Oh wait! I just needed to use the correct variable!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad that it worked! If you find any improvement in my answer please let me know I will change them, So that in future it will be helpful for someone who came across similar issue!

Comment: Mhm, now I just need to figure out how can I put that into an if statement. Like if the one of those numbers in that `result_id` equals a number from the `{item.id}` then do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171476/discussion-between-raaj-nadar-and-laney-williams).

Answer (score 2):

Everything you did is correct but variable you `declared outside render`? How can it be accessed in `render`

```
render(){
//considering array of objects in "data_use" state
 const result_id = this.state.data_use.map(function(val) {
      return val.id;
    }).join(',');

return(

     <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>
      <View>
       <Card>          
          <View>
          <Text>{result_id}</Text>
         </View>
       </Card>
       </View>
     </View>
   );
  }
```

Comment: can `ComponentDidMount` be inside the `render()`?

Comment: No, `ComponentDidMount` it is lifecycle method it should be outside render. @LaneyWilliams

Comment: `ComponentDidmount` is life cycle function you cant put that in render. Make API call in componentDidMount and store api result in state rest of code is in example. Just go through React documents

Comment: @Revansiddh I got it now! Thank you so much! This will be helpful also!